# php nginx X-Accel-Redirect headers

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers, x-accel-redirect

i have an issue regarding protecting folder with static files using nginx 
so basically i have root folder on nginx setup to :

```
/home/rise/rises/wwwdir
```

and the secured folder is :

```
/home/rise/rises/videop
```

as we can see i moved that folder outside root folder to prevent/allow only specific to see under criteria

when i first made a search before posting i read some ideas that to access the videop folder outside the root , i need to create alias in nginx conf like this which i made
and access internal

```
location /videop {
        root /home/rise/rises/;
         internal;
        }
```

however i have an issue on php side to load the video...

```
$aliasedFile = '/videop/5_.m3u8';
$filename = '5_.m3u8';
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type application/x-mpegURL ");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'');
header('X-Accel-Redirect: '. $aliasedFile);
readfile($aliasedFile);
```

i'm missing something ?

Comment: How does PHP know the root folder for `/videop`? Maybe you should pass the absolute path to `readfile` rather than the URL.

Comment: dont work...  $aliasedFile = '/videop/5_.m3u8';
    $realFile = '/home/rise/rises/videop/5_.m3u8'
    $filename = '5_.m3u8';
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: application/x-mpegURL");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'');
    header('X-Accel-Redirect: '. $aliasedFile);
    readfile($realFile);    no luck.. , dont work

Comment: anyone please i'm stuck now 5 days...

Answer (score 1):

Your `root` directive has a trailing `/` which will be followed by the leading `/` of the URL, so use:

```
location /videop {
  root /home/rise/rises;
  internal;
}
```

Your PHP has a badly formed header, which should include a `:` after `Content-Type`.

The PHP should should not include a body. The `readfile` is wrong. The whole purpose of the PHP is to issue an internal redirect which is picked up by `nginx`. So the PHP should return `header`s only.

Comment: there is : after content-type look at my previous post , i changed the directive / , i'm got headache with nginx & this new alias , as now when i removed the alias and put the videop as directory after wwwdir normally all work fine , i just want to protect that folder so i made out of the root but combining with alias no success over 5 days now , i feel very very tired... , can you pm ?

Comment: When you say it "all work fine" - Does it work using your PHP script with `X-Accel-Redirect`? If so, your new location block is probably not being loaded correctly into `nginx`. Or, the file permission are wrong for the `nginx` user. If you remove `internal;` everything should continue to work the same, except that you will be able to browse to the file directly - eliminating the PHP script (in order to help isolate the problem further).

Comment: no , here is current working code but with videop directory in root folder <?php ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
$file = "http://192.168.1.5:9000/videop/5_.m3u8";
header("location: $file");
$fd = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($fd)) {
    echo fread($fd, 1024 * 5);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    if (connection_aborted()){
        break;
    }
}
fclose ($fd);

exit();
die();  ?>

Comment: Why do you have `header("location: $file");` in your working PHP? Surely that header should only be used for redirection.

Comment: because this php page control login access to the video and if it's ok then redirect to the file..

Comment: @Krasic I'm sorry, but I don't understand how it works. It seems to set a header (as if intending to redirect) then sends the file anyway (as if a normal page). But I have no experience with video streaming - so I may be out of my depth.

Comment: because you dont request the file directly via full path , you go with a page like : www.website.com/stream.php?user=us&pass=ps?video=5 , so i check first user & pass if correct and redirect video id to real video path , i would like to make so to secure those link..